# Redirect to index.html page from server with message

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to traverse like :

index.html(With form data) --> save_message.php(Process form data) --> index.html(Show success/error message)

My html code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var messageForm = $('#message-form');
    messageForm.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');

        $.ajax({
            url: "save_message.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#message-form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                messageForm.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.type == 'success'){
                    alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
                    form_status.html('<p class="success-message">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000);
                    $('#message-form')[0].reset();
                }else if(data.type == 'error'){
                    alert("Error on query!");
                }
            }
          });         
    });
</script>

<form id="message-form" name="message-form" action="save_message.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name *</label> <input type="text" name="full_name"
                id="full_name" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email *</label> <input type="email" name="email"
                id="email" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="submit"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

And my code in save_message.php file :

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
    );

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $full_name = @trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['full_name'])); 
        $email = @trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])); 
    } 

    include 'conn.php';

    $sqlQuery = "insert into suggestion(full_name,email) values('$full_name','$email')";
    echo $sqlQuery;

    $result = @mysql_query($sqlQuery);
    if(!$result){
        $status = array(
            'type'=>'success',
            'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($status);  
 ?>
```

But it is not redirecting to index.html page.
Ratheer it is showing bellow line in save_message.php page.

```
insert into suggestion(full_name,email,phone,title,message,status) values('AAAA','parvej35@gmail.com','12345','AAAAAAAAAAA','sssssssss','New'){"type":"success","message":"Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you "}
```

Please help me.

Comment: you have `echo $sqlQuery;` after `$sqlQuery = "insert into ....`. Since you have `dataType: "json",`, you are expecting back `json`, but your `echo` is sending back text. Remove that line.

Comment: ok Thank you. NOW what should I do to get proper success/error message ???

Comment: @Sean, look at the queries, the displaying query is different from the query used in the code

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava so where do you think that line is coming from? You should know by now that most new posters never provide exact code throughout the entire question, with most of it being edited or copy/paste segments.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava just ignore the output line;

Comment: @Sean just ignore the output line;

Comment: @Sean I have removed echo $sqlQuery; BUT not working

Comment: @ParvejAhmed can you show us the response now?

Comment: @MoshFeu output is same as before.

Comment: The output is `insert into suggestion(full_name,email,phone,title,message,status) values('AAAA','parvej35@gmail.com','12345','AAAAAAAAAAA','sssssssss','New'){"type":"success","message":"Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you "}`?

Comment: @MoshFeu just ignore the output line;

Comment: Output line is :
insert into suggestion(full_name,email) values('AAAA','abc@gmail.com'){"typ‌​e":"success","message":"Thank you for contact us. As early as possible we will contact you "}

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava, Sean, MoshFeu
All of u r concern abt output not about main problem

Comment: But it is. Your main problem is that the output is not in `json` format, it's not convert to a javascript object. If you will fix the output, the problem will be solved.